# Shared FIFO control module between UART, PS/2 protocol, UART is ok, PS/2 has issue locking on to packets during read

Tags: fpga, synchronization, fifo, metastability

I have brought over a design from a previously provided source in my FPGA.   This is the FIFO controller for my system that gets instantiated in both UART sub system, as well as PS/2 sub system.  The FIFO worked well, visually at least for the UART side, but not entirely for the PS/2 side.

After some research I added a PS2_MODE parameter to switch between adding synchronizer between for wr signal and not adding any synchronizer for wr signal.  I don't fully have a handle if not having this present this is causing my mouse module to just keep displaying the last byte in the fifo received, even when I am not moving the mouse.  So I need help to fix this issue.

Do I need to synchronize the write side only of the PS/2 to make it compatible with my design's clock domain?  Do I need more alternate logic like encoding the write pointer, or read pointer as grey code.  I am a little new to FIFO design so I'd like help to proceed.   I am picturing the present state of the FIFO as synchronous, even though my UART is potentially not so, and the PS/2 module might actually be synchronous.

Am I going in the right direction to fix this?  Please help.

```verilog
  module fifo_ctrl
    #(
       parameter ADDR_WIDTH = 4,
       parameter PS2_MODE = 0 // set to 1 to use PS/2 mode with synchronized wr signal
    )
    (
       input logic clk, reset,
       input logic rd, wr,
       output logic empty, full,
       output logic [ADDR_WIDTH-1:0] w_addr,
       output logic [ADDR_WIDTH-1:0] r_addr
    );
    
    // signal declaration
    logic [ADDR_WIDTH-1:0] w_ptr_logic, w_ptr_next, w_ptr_succ;
    logic [ADDR_WIDTH-1:0] r_ptr_logic, r_ptr_next, r_ptr_succ;
    logic full_logic, empty_logic, full_next, empty_next;
    
    // synchronization signals
    logic rd_sync, wr_sync, wr_sync2;
    
    // fifo control logic
    // registers for status and read and write pointers
    always @(posedge clk) begin
       if (reset) begin
          w_ptr_logic <= 0;
          r_ptr_logic <= 0;
          full_logic <= 1'b0;
          empty_logic <= 1'b1;
       end
       else begin
          w_ptr_logic <= w_ptr_next;
          r_ptr_logic <= r_ptr_next;
          full_logic <= full_next;
          empty_logic <= empty_next;
       end
    
       if (PS2_MODE) begin
          //rd_sync <= rd; // add 1 cycle delay for read in PS/2 mode
          wr_sync <= wr_sync2;
          wr_sync2 <= wr;
       end else begin
          //rd_sync <= rd;
          wr_sync <= wr;
       end
    end
    assign rd_sync = rd;
     // fifo control logic
    // registers for status and read and write pointers
    always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
        if (reset) begin
          w_ptr_logic <= 0;
          r_ptr_logic <= 0;
          full_logic <= 1'b0;
          empty_logic <= 1'b1;
        end else begin
          w_ptr_logic <= w_ptr_next;
          r_ptr_logic <= r_ptr_next;
          full_logic <= full_next;
          empty_logic <= empty_next;
        end
    end
    
    // next-state logic for read and write pointers
    always_comb begin
    // successive pointer values
    w_ptr_succ = w_ptr_logic + 1;
    r_ptr_succ = r_ptr_logic + 1;
    
    // default: keep old values
    w_ptr_next = w_ptr_logic;
    r_ptr_next = r_ptr_logic;
    full_next = full_logic;
    empty_next = empty_logic;
    
    unique case ({wr_sync, rd_sync})
      2'b01: // read
        if (~empty_logic) begin // not empty
          r_ptr_next = r_ptr_succ;
          full_next = 1'b0;
          if (r_ptr_succ == w_ptr_logic) begin
            empty_next = 1'b1;
          end
        end
      2'b10: // write
        if (~full_logic) begin // not full
          w_ptr_next = w_ptr_succ;
          empty_next = 1'b0;
          if (w_ptr_succ == r_ptr_logic) begin
            full_next = 1'b1;
          end
        end
      2'b11: // write and read
        begin
          w_ptr_next = w_ptr_succ;
          r_ptr_next = r_ptr_succ;
        end
      default: ; // 2'b00; null statement; no op
    endcase
    end
    
    // output
    assign w_addr = w_ptr_logic;
    assign r_addr = r_ptr_logic;
    assign empty = empty_logic;
    assign full = full_logic;

  endmodule
```

EDIT with Revised Gray Code Addressing

```
module fifo_ctrl
#(   
   parameter ADDR_WIDTH = 4,
   parameter PS2_MODE = 0, // set to 1 to use PS/2 mode with synchronized wr signal
   parameter REGION_SIZE = 2 ** (ADDR_WIDTH - 1) // size of each region
)
(
   input logic clk, reset,
   input logic rd, wr,
   output logic empty, full,
   output logic [ADDR_WIDTH-1:0] w_addr,
   output logic [ADDR_WIDTH-1:0] r_addr
);

    // signal declaration
    logic [ADDR_WIDTH-1:0] w_ptr_logic, w_ptr_next, w_ptr_succ;
    logic [ADDR_WIDTH-1:0] r_ptr_logic, r_ptr_next, r_ptr_succ;
    reg [ADDR_WIDTH-1:0] wr_region = 0;
    reg [ADDR_WIDTH-1:0] rd_region = 0;
    logic full_logic, empty_logic, full_next, empty_next;
    
    // synchronization signals
    logic rd_sync, wr_sync, wr_sync2;
    logic read, write;
    
    // Gray code conversion
    logic [ADDR_WIDTH-1:0] w_ptr_gray;
    logic [ADDR_WIDTH-1:0] r_ptr_gray;
    
    always_comb begin
        w_ptr_gray[ADDR_WIDTH-1] = w_ptr_logic[ADDR_WIDTH-1];
        for (int i = ADDR_WIDTH-2; i >= 0; i--) begin
            w_ptr_gray[i] = w_ptr_logic[i+1] ^ w_ptr_logic[i];
        end
        r_ptr_gray[ADDR_WIDTH-1] = r_ptr_logic[ADDR_WIDTH-1];
        for (int i = ADDR_WIDTH-2; i >= 0; i--) begin
            r_ptr_gray[i] = r_ptr_logic[i+1] ^ r_ptr_logic[i];
        end
    end
    
    // synchronization
    always @(posedge clk) begin
       if (PS2_MODE) begin
          rd_sync <= rd; // add 1 cycle delay for read in PS/2 mode
          wr_sync <= wr_sync2;  //wr_sync now asserts for 1 cc, no more than that
          wr_sync2 <= wr;
       end
    end
    assign read = (PS2_MODE)? rd_sync : rd;
    assign write = (PS2_MODE)? wr_sync : wr;
    
    // fifo control logic
    // registers for status and read and write pointers
    always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
        if (reset) begin
          w_ptr_logic <= 0;
          r_ptr_logic <= 0;
          full_logic <= 1'b0;
          empty_logic <= 1'b1;
          wr_sync <= 0;
          wr_sync2 <= 0;
        end else begin
          w_ptr_logic <= w_ptr_next;
          r_ptr_logic <= r_ptr_next;
          full_logic <= full_next;
          empty_logic <= empty_next;
        end
    end
    
    // next-state logic for read and write pointers
    always_comb begin
      // Gray code successor values with wraparound
      for (int i = 0; i < ADDR_WIDTH; i++) begin
        w_ptr_succ[i] = w_ptr_logic[i] ^ (write & (w_ptr_gray[i] ^ w_ptr_gray[(i+1)%ADDR_WIDTH]));
        r_ptr_succ[i] = r_ptr_logic[i] ^ (read & (r_ptr_gray[i] ^ r_ptr_gray[(i+1)%ADDR_WIDTH]));
      end
      
      // default: keep old values
      w_ptr_next = w_ptr_logic;
      r_ptr_next = r_ptr_logic;
      full_logic = (wr_region + REGION_SIZE == rd_region) && (w_addr == r_addr);
      empty_logic = (wr_region == rd_region) && (w_addr == r_addr);
      full_next = full_logic;
      empty_next = empty_logic;

      unique case ({write, read})
        2'b01: // read
        if (~empty_logic) begin // not empty
          if (r_ptr_gray == (rd_region + REGION_SIZE - 1)) begin
            rd_region = rd_region + REGION_SIZE;
            r_ptr_next = rd_region;
          end else begin
            r_ptr_next = r_ptr_succ;
          end
          full_next = 1'b0;
          if (r_ptr_succ == w_ptr_logic) begin
            empty_next = 1'b1;
          end
        end
        2'b10: // write
        if (~full_logic) begin // not full
          if (w_ptr_gray == (wr_region + REGION_SIZE - 1)) begin
            wr_region = wr_region + REGION_SIZE;
            w_ptr_next = wr_region;
          end else begin
            w_ptr_next = w_ptr_succ;
          end
          empty_next = 1'b0;
          if (w_ptr_succ == r_ptr_logic) begin
            full_next = 1'b1;
          end
        end
        2'b11: // write and read
        begin
          w_ptr_next = w_ptr_succ;
          r_ptr_next = r_ptr_succ;
        end
        default: ; // 2'b00; null statement; no op
     endcase
   end
   
   // output
   assign w_addr = w_ptr_logic;
   assign r_addr = r_ptr_logic;
  
   assign full = full_logic;
   assign empty = empty_logic;
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Verification of the Problem**

Turns out after I created a new testbench and spent about a few weeks checking the root cause, the fifo on the PS/2 side (same module as working UART fifo) was faulty in that two byte writes were writing to one address.  Modifying the logic to use a 4 byte shift register in hopes of fixing the solution did produce favorable results,  I relied upon writing to the shift register then writing to the fifo, but on initial run,  my PS/2 initialization sequence was not passing to completion leading me to believe there was a problem in synchronization.   So, I took a leap of faith and commented out the shift register and only left the only control logic from a new design I created for the FIFO and amazingly the output worked flawlessly.

**The Problem**

The FIFO control logic had issues all this time causing the data to misalign or even mis read  because bytes were written to consecutive locations at given parts of the write cycle so that would leave my output obviously corrupt.

**Resolution**

This confirmed my initial observation and finally became resolved by replacing the fifo control module entirely.  Also, I upped the baud rate to about 115200 so that my UART fifo depth would not be need to be that much as stream rate would become sufficient enough to not need a deep fifo.   Glad to say this is resolved now.

**New FIFO module**
https://github.com/vahejab/arty_sv_sampler/blob/e70c21413e3fedac4ebccac5a619b0790ebed2e2/arty_sv_sampler.srcs/sources_1/imports/code_listing_sv/fpga_mcs_sv_src/hdl/mmio/mmio_support/fifo/fifo.sv

**Summary of Changes in Latest Commit**
https://github.com/vahejab/arty_sv_sampler/commit/e70c21413e3fedac4ebccac5a619b0790ebed2e2

Answer (score 1):

When performing clock domain crossing (CDC) via a FIFO several additional modifications to a single domain FIFO are required.

Namely the following:

- The WRITE logic needs to be on the write domain clock
- The READ logic needs to be on the read domain clock
- The WR_PTR and RD_PTR need to be Gray-Coded so that the address does not corrupt

There is a fairly good tutorial [here](https://www.verilogpro.com/asynchronous-fifo-design/) that I would start with. Once you've read through this feel free to edit your question to fill any gaps.

Comment: I have started looking at the article, so thank you tremendously.  Also on inspection the memory cells were not moving orderly there were gaps which I suspect was due to a binary encoded addressing scheme.  I am looking into converting to gray-coded addressing scheme.  Since my UART presented no issues as far as I see, I left that version unmodified though I am not sure if that's a good idea since it works asynchronously unmodified.  The PS2, has a clock on the write and a clock on the read which I made in the same domain.    I used synchronizers on write, read signals. I'll give an update.

Comment: I don't yet know why the UART was supposedly transmitting, receiving with out any synchronization,  because I vaguely understood it to be asynchronous.  However, it did not even have gray coding implemented.   So I am a bit confused.   I used substantial help to generate an updated version.  Please provide necessary comments if desired.  I am in the process of trying it.  It uses gray encoding for addressing scheme, and separate registers for read and write.  From understanding this is a synchronous fifo, for PS2 but uses asynchronous elements.  See question revision.

Comment: Further research led to the conclusion that UART has a baud rate on tx, and rx sides controlling data flow, that leads to less issues with synchronization and probably is why my data was operating under one clock domain,  UART does not send a separate clock as PS/2.  Since PS/2 sends a separate clock, this means I would receive data asynchronously because I am dealing with two clock domains, async with respect to each other.  That's why I need the synchronizer logic present on the PS/2 receive fifo much more so than the UART rx/tx fifo (same module as PS/2) as well as gray code addressing.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. Is the FIFO used communication between the PS/2 AND UART or is it entirely internal to each and you're using some other method communicating between the 2?

Comment: I have separate modules using same instance of FIFO, namely UART and PS2, but they use the same module just different wrapper logic, and in my case I made them use different modes of FIFO.  All of a sudden after about 3 months of work on this, I got some progress.  The mouse movements do trigger outputs on movements only.  Unclear if the FIFO adjustments helped, but I did modify the embedded C++ logic not shown, to only enqueue to a software FIFO is rx_byte() was not 0 empty FIFO and then after 4 successive bytes enqueued I dequeued 4 bytes consecutively so that I would get entire movement.

Comment: Critical changes made, committed to GItHub, 
https://github.com/vahejab/arty_sv_sampler/commit/a99806d411bc6940c5e2e35de7497589ea47e8ee

Comment: I employ a Microblaze MCS processor to run a C++ embedded application to control data reception and transmission